# Unity Facebook SDK error (Building Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/libil2cpp.so failed with output)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-unity-sdk

I have a building problem and it occurred after importing facebook SDK into the game. Does anybody have a solution?

[Player Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QxVC.png)

> Building Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/libil2cpp.so failed
> with output:
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_init_m7F37E8D602676BCF848A03B7E02C9FBECE38281F': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:334: undefined reference to` init'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_login_m690FB8B413DB1BA3F10CE5EFB74C2678B3FD166B': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:363: undefined reference to` login'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_Logout_m765321CDCDD0B2FF217EC45ED32F7EC33AA74D55': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:380: undefined reference to` logout'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_logout_m88D882A6204D48DC0739D5BE473F301DE9227223': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:380: undefined reference to` logout'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_ActivateApp_m2FB27437D22180800F51B9EECAD053BC08C28FF7': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:389: undefined reference to` activateApp'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_activateApp_mE3803C0C9EA77C9C232A2C565965646541C29826': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:389: undefined reference to` activateApp'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_logAppEvent_m5D5691C6237E414AEC10369CC0BDC60A994B1900': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:406: undefined reference to` logAppEvent'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_logPurchase_m4A27021F8AA81EB77DB1DEF64EA4DA1E36673263': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:431: undefined reference to` logPurchase'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_ui_mB7396CDEFEDD3404DAC9B417AA53B92A7E9D6B95': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:460: undefined reference to` ui'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_InitScreenPosition_mF792D82FC8A3D5C1AF857331EA31F367E8CC6D8F': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:481: undefined reference to` initScreenPosition'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/4osi_ity.Canvas.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_initScreenPosition_mE172A376716C026B9A69639DEA3178CD8970E6AF': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:481: undefined reference to` initScreenPosition'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBInit_m9E848A275B5550D65BC53C744317880C735344C4': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1329: undefined reference to` IOSFBInit'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_EnableProfileUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange_m7E17E4120ACC261DD43C20247E345702C4D17B3A': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1350: undefined reference to` IOSFBEnableProfileUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBEnableProfileUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange_mBB9A4D8055DFEAF0D92FE7540C33658ECDFAFC9E': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1350: undefined reference to` IOSFBEnableProfileUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBLoginWithTrackingPreference_mB9CA64864AB8141024658470F0C44E4AEF88EABF': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1388: undefined reference to` IOSFBLoginWithTrackingPreference'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBLogInWithReadPermissions_m0DC1BA8A935CBDEF89CAAD717D3B95BCEFA608FB': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1363: undefined reference to` IOSFBLogInWithReadPermissions'
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1363:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBLogInWithReadPermissions' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBLogInWithPublishPermissions_mD8D6CE9F5E0FECD8FF05A0A26DF68E04B84A722C':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1413:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBLogInWithPublishPermissions' /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1413: undefined reference to` IOSFBLogInWithPublishPermissions'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_LogOut_m67FFB90622E00A6269723C7A947922BA557D6878': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1426: undefined reference to` IOSFBLogOut'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBLogOut_m9DE0C89B86F79DDE765FB784C1F5CC4C52B610EB': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1426: undefined reference to` IOSFBLogOut'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBSetPushNotificationsDeviceTokenString_mC394DB6C2B511EFE04037B12AA00AADD766F8411': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1439: undefined reference to` IOSFBSetPushNotificationsDeviceTokenString'
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1439:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBSetPushNotificationsDeviceTokenString' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBSetShareDialogMode_m182D0C72598346A9F6D21E61FD079D97FADD096D':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1452:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBSetShareDialogMode' /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1452: undefined reference to` IOSFBSetShareDialogMode'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBShareLink_m244772DE8F9F0F3ACB329315357E94C196A4D106': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1477: undefined reference to` IOSFBShareLink'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBFeedShare_m2B561569C130A1C35FF79164EA410F4A0A3896D8': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1530: undefined reference to` IOSFBFeedShare'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBAppRequest_mE73FEE39C895EB8C6A8218B31692E18BFE7BCE5A': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1625: undefined reference to` IOSFBAppRequest'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBOpenGamingServicesFriendFinder_mD2E572D6973A03E70B78AC4A51BBB8C8450531DC': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1946: undefined reference to` IOSFBOpenGamingServicesFriendFinder'
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1946:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBOpenGamingServicesFriendFinder' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_FBAppEventsActivateApp_mF184ADFDFED02CF0E84BA3082CCE0F632075E907':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1684:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAppEventsActivateApp' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBAppEventsActivateApp_mC89C64D889D79381745E77F51F8986732C6435D8':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1684:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAppEventsActivateApp' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBCreateGamingContext_m6E96E2EB736B665628C22880FACFCA0A232A70E2':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2077:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBCreateGamingContext' /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2077: undefined reference to` IOSFBCreateGamingContext'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBSwitchGamingContext_mFE3AEA6A3FF93B6894DC29346C8B7FF9F22FCFA1': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2094: undefined reference to` IOSFBSwitchGamingContext'
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2094:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBSwitchGamingContext' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBChooseGamingContext_m0D2AD6EA4EE62C60F975B6044214A420142C1C13':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2111:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBChooseGamingContext' /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2111: undefined reference to` IOSFBChooseGamingContext'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBGetCurrentGamingContext_mC4E7C37F010272CC79AC85C8E812A15F76AA54B5': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2124: undefined reference to` IOSFBGetCurrentGamingContext'
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2124:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBGetCurrentGamingContext' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBAppEventsLogEvent_m5E365254A1B749D20A931BC3ACBB827A252D4682':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1731:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAppEventsLogEvent' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBAppEventsLogPurchase_mF184673928ACAB2DBCFEDEF3BF5AE199B18A0D2B':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1808:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAppEventsLogPurchase' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_FBAppEventsSetLimitEventUsage_mC2F1B049CD6AB38814E8AB387071FBE40ED7C879':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1847:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAppEventsSetLimitEventUsage' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBAppEventsSetLimitEventUsage_m859AA1074D592E634BC25952B08E6CD70CB66C92':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1847:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAppEventsSetLimitEventUsage' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_FBAutoLogAppEventsEnabled_mD94221CBCAEC74ED3B5AD37D4C8780B25D5E58FB':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1856:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAutoLogAppEventsEnabled' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBAutoLogAppEventsEnabled_m23684AD505631EA0091A272F2C950E3D672D401E':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1856:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAutoLogAppEventsEnabled' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_FBAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled_m88D77F948ECD2C3EB1CF478B6183EA109D6834AA':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1865:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled_mA4741E6A9DB0EADD2869418BFB8A9A0252A7FA60':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1865:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBAdvertiserTrackingEnabled_m7243C8E8B98A4362A054D33B15659B7D2C1368E8':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1874:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBAdvertiserTrackingEnabled' /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1874: undefined reference to` IOSFBAdvertiserTrackingEnabled'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBGetAppLink_m764D8E9CADDF3ED90E7B9E73D0251A5B68C29EE0': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1884: undefined reference to` IOSFBGetAppLink'
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1884:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBGetAppLink' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBSdkVersion_m94974EFF5F874DF15D953545FB1F96985C3D3D57':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1893:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBSdkVersion' /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1893: undefined reference to` IOSFBSdkVersion'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBSetUserID_mF46C44E4475B28719E3AACC605678C84CEA361D4': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1933: undefined reference to` IOSFBSetUserID'
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:1933:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBSetUserID' Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function` IOSWrapper_IOSFBGetUserID_m81332794E49DF7B6D618C4A01E3A366ECFF6BB19':
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2133:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBGetUserID' /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2133: undefined reference to` IOSFBGetUserID'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBSetDataProcessingOptions_m2E10A93444CB5E222F9CE5E6751E4000AA7E12D9': /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2168: undefined reference to` IOSFBSetDataProcessingOptions'
> /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2168:
> undefined reference to `IOSFBSetDataProcessingOptions' /Users/mce/Champy/bladebender3d/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.IOS.cpp:2168: undefined reference to` IOSFBSetDataProcessingOptions'
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/fzf9_.Unity.IOS.o: In function `IOSWrapper_IOSFBCu
> Building Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/libil2cpp.so failed with output:
> Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Facebook.Unity.Canvas.cpp:334:
> error: undefined reference to 'init'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).